# Does PostgreSQL index null values?

Tags: postgresql, index, null

If I have a table like so:

```
Food
-----------------
name | price | x
```

Let's say I create an index on name & price, but the database has a bunch of null values for both name & price in some of the rows. Does PostgreSQL automatically skip indexing those rows? I heard this behavior might have changed in later releases.

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328). Also asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976220/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cross posted and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976220/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since at least PostgreSQL 8.3, PostgreSQL indexes `NULL` using a bitmap on the index. That means "yes" it's indexed. Except it takes a bit, rather than a byte[s]. There is no speed advantage insofar as btree indexes are concerned with using a non-`NULL` value. It will work just as you'd expect.

Dragons here: for more information see this,

- http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/11/11/discovering-the-computer-science-behind-postgres-indexes